# Problem with sequence and rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n=\frac {(2n+1)(n^2-2n+2)}{(n^2+1)(n^4+4)}$, for every $n \ge 1$. Show that
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\dots(1+a_n) \lt \sqrt e.$$

MY TRY: Let us denote $x_n=\ln(1+a_1)+\ln (1+a_2) + \dots + \ln(1+a_n)$. The problem is now to show that $x_n \lt \frac 1 2.$ I showed that $x_n$ is increasing, so I think about proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n= \frac 1 2$. I am stuck now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$n^4 + 4 = (n^2 + 2)^2 - (2n)^2 = (n^2 + 2n + 2)(n^2 - 2n + 2)$$

Thus $$a_n = \frac{2n+1}{(n^2 + 1)(n^2 + 2n + 2)}$$

Notice that the difference of the terms in the denominator is the numerator.

Thus if $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2 + 1}$ then

$$a_n = b_n - b_{n+1}$$

Note that $b_1 = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now use $\log (1 + a) \lt a$ to get

$$\sum \log(1+a_k) \le \sum a_k = b_{1} - b_{n+1} \lt b_1 = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: btw, the limit is not $1/2$.